# Android Application Subclass Across Activities

Tags: android

I'm running into a NullPointerException, and I can't seem to figure out why. I wouldn't say I'm that experienced in android, so it seems easy for me to get lost when debugging these... :(

I've got an Application subclass defined as follows:

```
public class UserData extends Application {
    private String email, firstName, lastName;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String str) {
        email = str;
    }

}
```

In one activity (loginpage), I set the email string:

```
UserData user = (UserData)getApplication();
user.setEmail(results);
```

When I log getEmail(), I see the results in this activity just fine.

In another activity (dashboard), I get the email string as follows:

```
UserData user = (UserData)getApplication();
Log.d("Email: ", user.getEmail());
```

This time, user.getEmail() returns a nullpointer. Can someone point out why this is occurring? I've got the subclass defined in my Manifest like this:

```
<application
        android:name=".UserData"></application>
```

Error Log:

```
-12 18:10:51.261  19471-19471/habitatfinal.habitatfinal E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: habitatfinal.habitatfinal, PID: 19471
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{habitatfinal.habitatfinal/habitatfinal.habitatfinal.dashboard}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
        at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
        at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
        at habitatfinal.habitatfinal.dashboard.onCreate(dashboard.java:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: Could you post the logcat with the stack trace? NPE is on `user` or `instance`?

Comment: I edited and simplified my subclass and posted the error log.

Comment: Are you sure that user.setEmail(results) is not setting it to null?

Comment: I `Log.d("Data: ", user.getEmail());` and get a result in the first activity. Its only in the second activity that it returns NPE.

Comment: add a `log.d` in `setEmail` just to make sure it's not set to `null` from somewhere else.

Comment: I tried that just now. Set is only being called once, and the values are correct. Its so weird.

Comment: What if you do `Log.d("app: " +  getApplication())`, is it the same id in both activities?

Comment: Hm, how do I get this Id? String.valueOf()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was going on. The problem is onPostExecute doesn't necessarily run after the onCreate() method finishes running. Because they are two different threads, the subclass may not be initialized before the program passes the intent into the next activity.

Therefore, the variables in the object weren't set before it hit the new Activity.